# Notation about commutative diagrams and their vertices

Tags: category-theory, notation

Usually vertices of a commutative diagram are labeled with objects like $A\overset{f}{\leftrightarrow} B$.

But now I want to distinguish between vertices of the diagram even if they happen to correspond to the same object.

So I want to draw a diagram like $A\overset{f}{\leftrightarrow} A$ as $0\overset{f}{\leftrightarrow} 1$ where $0$ and $1$ are numbers labeling quiver vertices.

But the notation like $0\overset{f}{\leftrightarrow} 1$ is already reserved for **objects** $0$ and $1$ not for the **numbers** labeling diagram vertices.

Please advise which notation to use for both:

- express my idea
- be non-contradictory
- agree (if possible) with customary notation for commutative diagrams.

Hm, well, maybe use different **colors** for objects of the category in which I draw the diagram and for vertex numbers? Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, what's about $0[A]\overset{f}{\leftrightarrow} 1[A]$ or $A[0]\overset{f}{\leftrightarrow} A[1]$?

Comment: The customary visual notation distinguishes between two vertices with the same object by spatial separation (as in your example with $A \rightarrow A$). The customary formal definition as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory) distinguishes the vertices because they are distinct in the index category. So I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @RobArthan But I need to explicitly refer to different vertices in my proof text. Well, maybe I should just say like "top right" node of the square diagram?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. You could talk geometrically about the diagram as you suggest, or you could display the diagram of the index category alongside the commuting diagram it indexes (or on top of it as you suggest in your comment).